# file wont encrypt blowfish c++

Tags: c++, encryption, blowfish

Hello I want to encrypt a file with blowfish in c++ but it wont work at all. i gets only the same content back from the encrytion. someone that can help me out?

```
char * memblock;
long size;
printf("init params");
ifstream file ("/encryptfile.txt", ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
if (file.is_open())
{
  size = file.tellg();
  memblock = new char [size];
  file.seekg (0, ios::beg);
  printf("init all of it");
  file.read (memblock, size);
  printf("read file");


}
else printf("Unable to open file");

long multipleSize = (size/8 +1)*8;

long paddingSize = size * multipleSize;

char * outMemBlock;
outMemBlock = new char[paddingSize];
memset(outMemBlock, 0, paddingSize);

CBlowFish objBlowFish((unsigned char*)"abcdefgh",8);
printf("make blowfish file");
objBlowFish.Encrypt((unsigned char*)memblock,(unsigned char*)outMemBlock,16000);
printf("encryption done");

ofstream myfile ("/encryptfile.txt");
 if (myfile.is_open())
 {
   myfile << outMemBlock;
   myfile.close();
 }
 else cout << "Unable to open file";
```

Comment: You'll need to break down the code a little more, where does it go wrong?

Comment: it wont give any error but i think it goes rong on objBlowfish.encrypt

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using ECB mode, which is the default according to the [description](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1400/A-C-Implementation-of-the-Blowfish-Encryption-Decr) (presuming we are talking about the same library):

```
void Encrypt(unsigned char* buf, size_t n, int iMode=ECB);
void Decrypt(unsigned char* buf, size_t n, int iMode=ECB);
```

Also described on the same page are the implications:

> The first variant of the `Encrypt()` function is used for in place encryption of a block of data of the specified size applying the specified operation mode. The block size should be a multiple of 8. This function can operate in the following modes: ECB, CBC or CFB. In ECB mode, chaining is not used. If the same block is encrypted twice with the same key, the resulting ciphertext blocks are the same.

So you should use the CBC or CFB mode instead and provide a random IV in the constructor (initial chaining value called `roChain`):

```
CBlowFish(unsigned char* ucKey, size_t n, const SBlock& roChain = SBlock(0UL,0UL));
```

Commonly the IV is prefixed to the ciphertext and retrieved & skipped before decryption.

Comment: I'm presuming here that something gets encrypted, not that you are left with the plaintext.